# Analytics event tracking auto-populate

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick

I'm trying to write a short javascript that would automatically insert the "onclick" and target="_blank" attributes into every external link.

I found the documentation on Google on how to manually do it for every link, but I've got a fairly sizeable website to maintain. There's no way I'm going to be able to accurately add the OnClick attribute to every single external link manually.

Reference: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

I understand how the logic should flow, but I've never been good with syntax. The pseudo code probably looks like this:

```js
<script>
var destinationUrl = "whatever is in the href"

Check every link on my page

if destinationUrl is not "mydomain.com"
  add target="_blank"
  add onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound', 'Click', 'destinationUrl', '1');"
endif
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have analytics.js, gtag.js or GTM on your page?

Comment: I recommend using Google Tag Manager and its in-built click listeners for this use case

Comment: I'm using analytics.js. I haven't gotten into tag manager, something else always seems to come up.

Comment: No suggestions on how to finish the syntax?

Comment: Bump Bump Bump Bump

Comment: Come on Stack Overflow, I know you can do it. This is an easy Vanilla JavaScript question. I believe in you.